# Is it possible to create a View with read only option in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently having the latest version of `MySQL`(ver 8.0.2) and I'm trying to create a `read-only` *View*.

This is how my query looks like:

```
CREATE VIEW Emp_Salary3 AS
SELECT Empid, Ename, Date_Joined, Salary, Dcode 
FROM Employees
WHERE Salary < 35000
WITH READ ONLY;
```

But then the response I got was:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'READ ONLY' at line 5

Hence I checked the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-check-option.html) as well, it doesn't have a **READ-ONLY** option whatsoever. Is there a work around for this?

Any help could be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support `WITH READ ONLY` for [`CREATE VIEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html).

It is possible to create a read-only view in an indirect way: create an user that has the `SELECT` privilege on all tables and `CREATE VIEW` privilege then use this user to create the view and specify `SQL SECURITY DEFINER` in the `CREATE VIEW` statement:

```
CREATE 
    DEFINER = CURRENT_USER
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW Emp_Salary3 AS
SELECT Empid, Ename, Date_Joined, Salary, Dcode 
FROM Employees
WHERE Salary < 35000
```

The line `DEFINER = CURRENT_USER` is not needed if you use the limited user to create the view.

Or you can use an admin user to create the view and in this case the line `DEFINER =` must contain the name of the user that will own the view.

The documentation explains:

> MySQL checks view privileges like this:
>
> At view definition time, the view creator must have the privileges needed to use the top-level objects accessed by the view. For example, if the view definition refers to table columns, the creator must have some privilege for each column in the select list of the definition, and the `SELECT` privilege for each column used elsewhere in the definition. If the definition refers to a stored function, only the privileges needed to invoke the function can be checked. The privileges required at function invocation time can be checked only as it executes: For different invocations, different execution paths within the function might be taken.
>
> The user who references a view must have appropriate privileges to access it (`SELECT` to select from it, `INSERT` to insert into it, and so forth.)
>
> When a view has been referenced, privileges for objects accessed by the view are checked against the privileges held by the view `DEFINER` account or invoker, depending on whether the `SQL SECURITY` characteristic is `DEFINER` or `INVOKER`, respectively.

This means the users of the view must have at least `SELECT` privilege for the view. Then, if the `SQL SECURITY` is `DEFINER` then the privileges of the `DEFINER` user are applied to the tables and views used in the view definition.

Comment: Is it a good workaround to just create views by formulas? Example: `CREATE VIEW \`foo\` as SELECT concat(\`name\`, '') as \`name\`, \`price\` * 1 as \`price\` FROM \`bar\``? This makes immutable columns.

Comment: @robo-robok I "feel" like the answer is that's not good. Besides involving a per-column custom calculation, it seems hackish even it was really easy (for large queries it may not be easy and it reduces readability). Axiac's answer proposes using MySQL privileges which seems much more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Clear IS_UPDATABLE in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS table after creating the view (see [information-schema-views-table.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema-views-table.html))

Answer (score 0):

If the view has a join in it, then MYSQL will make that view read only (since it can't update composite views) but its a bit of an extreme measure

Comment: Usually joining data leads to a performance penalty, I would choose other answers